# Add multiple domains in x-frame-options on header with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-headers

I would like to add multiple domains in X-Frame-Options, because I must authorize facebook and messenger.

I tried many things, for example...

I created a middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FrameHeadersMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM https://www.messenger.com/');
        $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM https://www.facebook.com/');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

But only facebook is added...

[image]

Edit : I use the http referer with this :

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Request;

    class FrameHeadersMiddleware
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $response = $next($request);

            if(Request::server('HTTP_REFERER') === 'www.messenger.com'){
                $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM https://www.messenger.com/');
            }

            if(Request::server('HTTP_REFERER') === 'www.facebook.com'){
                $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM https://www.facebook.com/');
            }

            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is not possible this way. You can not specify the header multiple times, and it allows for only one URI. You need to output it specifically for whatever domain is framing your stuff in the first place.

Comment: Is facebook going to load your page in an iframe?

Comment: @apokryfos I read this here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#iframe

Comment: I would like to use the webview, it's work, but on desktop, I have not the "modal", there is a redirection in a new tab and I would like to have a modal (own an iFrame) @apokryfos

Comment: @CBroe do you have a documentation please ? I read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple `X-Frame-Options` headers at the same time.

See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034#page-8):

> 2.3.2.3.  Usage Design Pattern and Example Scenario for the ALLOW-FROM
> Parameter
>
> As the "ALLOW-FROM" field only supports one serialized-origin, in
> cases when the server wishes to allow more than one resource to frame
> its content, the following design pattern can fulfill that need:
>
> 1. A page that wants to render the requested content in a frame
>    supplies its own origin information to the server providing the
>    content to be framed via a query string parameter.
> 2. The server verifies that the hostname meets its criteria, so that
>    the page is allowed to be framed by the target resource.  This
>    may, for example, happen via a lookup of a whitelist of trusted
>    domain names that are allowed to frame the page.  For example,
>    for a Facebook "Like" button, the server can check to see that
>    the supplied hostname matches the hostname(s) expected for that
>    "Like" button.
> 3. The server returns the hostname in "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM"
>    if the proper criteria was met in step #2.
> 4. The browser enforces the "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM" header.

Comment: and the workaround here is to do something like (edited) `if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] === 'www.messenger.com') { $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM https://www.messenger.com/'); }` in the middleware.

Comment: @ceejayoz — No. If that worked, then you could just do "SAME ORIGIN". Do what I quoted in my answer.

Comment: This *is* what's in your answer - it's code for implementing #2 and #3.

Comment: @ceejayoz — No. `$request->getHttpHost()` will give you the host name of the site that hosts the page being loaded into the iframe. You need to check the host of the page with the `<iframe>` tag in it.

Comment: Ah! Need more coffee. I see it now. `if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` instead.